# Как привязать домен к хостингу nic.ru?

Tags: хостинг, dns, домен

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: https://skr.sh/sAXmIYKdQBd?a]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке открыть сайт по нужному домену получаю такое окно (полагаю, что привязать домен к хостингу не получилось). Мой сайт открывается только через хостинговые бесплатные некрасивые домены, если так можно выразиться.

Comment: Удалил "некрасивые бесплатные" домены, потому что думал, что они противоречат условию тарифа S ( доступен только 1 домен), оставил только один платный в списке, не помогло.
Выбрал dns-master, теперь в статусе висит "услуга предоставляется", но полагаю, это не поможет...

Comment: хостинг и домен на одном аккаунте, но я уже пробовал dns-хостинг, но не дождался

Comment: я написал ответ, потом засомневался, пошел проверять - и удалил свой ответ... В общем, у nic.ru применяется какая то магия: еслиу них покупаешь "и домен, и DNS - хостинг" - то настраивать ничего не надо. все записи, которые нужны для открытия сайта в браузере добавляются на DNS - сервера автоматически, и я даже не нашел, как этим управлять. (Именно поэтому я такой уровень магии не очень люблю.) Но у Вас на верхней картинке написано "домен делегирован на сторонние DNS серверы" - видимо, всё дело в этом. Если его делегировать на DNS серверы в рамках услуги DNS - мастер - всё должно починиться

Comment: @S.H. написано, только вот это их DNS серверы)